# Possible Ways to Build a Virtual Private Cloud with VPS nodes

Tags: networking, vps, vlan

I have a number of internet based VPS nodes used for prototyping that I would like to connect together as if they were on the same secure private LAN, like a VLAN. I have been looking for ways that they can be connected together in this manner. Unfortunately, I am not finding the right terminology because all my searches end up leading to the proprietary solutions for AWS, Google, IBM, etc.

I am familiar with VPNs and see some older posts about connecting multiple VPS nodes with individual VPN connections. I am wondering what standard approaches or tool sets are used for this software level VLAN definition in Linux outside of services offered by the likes of Amazon and Google cloud infrastructure.

Comment: read some doc about VXLAN (or similar things. GENEVE?) https://vincent.bernat.ch/en/blog#tag-network-vxlan

Answer (score 0):

`VLAN` means `Virtual Lan`. It's a way to implement isolated LANs on a single LAN (aka, copper and equipments are shared) so unless:

- Your VPS are hosted by the same provider on the same physical LAN
- Your hoster is OK to create you a dedicated VLAN on its equipements.

Using VLAN will be impossible.

`VPN` means `Virtual Private Network`. It's a way to interconnect several LANs (or hosts that are part of several LANs) into a virtual one.

Regarding your needs, you may use VPN to interconnect your VPS.

Regarding your question about the big, proprietaries cloud provider, they have their own datacenter, with dedicated network and equipements, so i guess (but it's hard to tell since its totally opaque for users) that they manage private cloud using VLAN isolation.